# Download image using Dynamics 365 Web API

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-webapi

I am trying to download the image from Dataverse using Dynamics Web API.

I am able to succeed in that using `{{webapiurl}}sample_imageattributedemos(d66ecb6c-4fd1-ec11-a7b5-6045bda5603f)/entityimage/$value`

But when I try to download the full/actual size image - I am getting the file with the reduced size - `{{webapiurl}}sample_imageattributedemos(d66ecb6c-4fd1-ec11-a7b5-6045bda5603f)/entityimage/$value?fullsize=true`.

I tried to download the image using the sample code where additionally I have added **CanStoreFullImage = true** attribute.

Please find below code snippet for the reference:

```
CreateAttributeRequest createEntityImageRequest = new CreateAttributeRequest
{
    EntityName = _customEntityName.ToLower(),
    Attribute = new ImageAttributeMetadata
    {
        SchemaName = "EntityImage", //The name is always EntityImage
                                //Required level must be AttributeRequiredLevel.None
        RequiredLevel = new AttributeRequiredLevelManagedProperty(AttributeRequiredLevel.None),
        DisplayName = new Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Label("Image", 1033),
        Description = new Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Label("An image to show with this demonstration.", 1033),
        CanStoreFullImage = true,
        IsPrimaryImage = false,
    }
};
```

How can I achieve this - to download the full size image using Web API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the correct syntax is *size=full*, not *fullsize=true*

to build such requests you can use my tool [Dataverse REST Builder](https://github.com/GuidoPreite/DRB), you can find the operations to deal with Image fields under the *Manage Image Data* request type

Comment: I tried that _size=full_ approach, but it always returns *204 - No content* despite of having an image.

Comment: Any luck with it?

Comment: did you try to download the image with my tool?